# Display a custom field value in Woocommerce email notification template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, I am using **"WC Fields Factory"** plugin to create a **`'serial'`** custom field. I need to display its value in `/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php` template file.

I have tried to use:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_serial", true );
```

But it does not work.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly **`$order`** with all `WC_Order` methods in this email template, to get the Order ID, this way:

```
// Get the Order ID (WooCommerce retro-compatibility)
$order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

// Get "serial" custom field value
$serial = get_post_meta($order_id, "wccaf_serial", true );

// Display "serial" custom field value
echo '<p>'.__('Serial', 'woocommerce') . $serial . '</p>';
```

Please read: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates **via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

---

Also instead of overriding this template, you can use any available hook for example like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'action_wc_email_order_details' 50, 4 );
function action_wc_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // Get the Order ID (WooCommerce retro-compatibility)
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

    // Get "serial" custom field value
    $serial = get_post_meta($order_id, "wccaf_serial", true );

    // Display "serial" custom field value
    echo '<p>'.__('Serial', 'woocommerce') . $serial . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works in WooCommerce 2.6.x or 3+

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It really was useful. But unfortunately I still can not get the desired result. I get the **text (Serial) + the empty value** of the variable.
I once again checked the name and value of the field _"serial"_ but it did not help (I use the **admin field** with a **text value**). Anyway, I will try to continue.
Thank you.

Comment: @Fost You should check directly in the database in wp_postmeta table searching  for "wccaf_serial" meta_key. If you dont get it, then search for an order ID (post_id) to see if you get any "serial" meta_key …

Comment: Thanks, I did a search and got 5 fields (maybe I copied and deleted this field for verification) with the name **"wccaf_serial"**. First field with value "meta_value" {"type":"text","label":"serial","name":"serial","r.... Other fields are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WP HTML Mail. This plugin has an integrated mailbuilder for WooCommerce emails. You can edit the content of your mail in WordPress editor and add custom fields from menu "Placeholder".
Here are some screenshots: http://wp-html-mail.com/woocommerce-custom-email-content/